# How to prove existance and construct finite-state transducer between two different FSM?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, transducers

For example I have 2 simple FSM. I will use regular expression for clarity.

```
FSM1 = 1+ = [1,11,111,...]
FSM2 = 2+ = [2,22,222,...]
FST = 1/2 = [1->2,11->22,...]
```

What is the general way to prove that there exists finite-state transducer that maps each string from the set defined by FSM1 to a string defined by FSM2? What is the algorithm to construct such transducer?

I want to have the next properties from mapping:

1. ((1))=(2), where (1) is the regular language accepted by the first FSM, (2) the one for the second FSM,  is some transducer
2. is bijective mapping from (1) to (2)
3. It have to specifically map the th string from (1) to the th string from (2) using lexicographic order

Comment: What properties do you want the mapping to have?  A mapping that maps every input to `2` would appear to meet all of your stated requirements, but I doubt you'll be happy with that, so I suspect some requires are missing or not clearly stated.  Do you want $T(L(F_1)) = L(F_2)$, where $L(F_1)$ is the regular language accepted by the first FSM and $L(F_2)$ the one for the second FSM, and $T$ is some transducer?  Do you want $T$ to be a bijective mapping from $L(F_1)$ to $L(F_2)$?  Does it have to specifically map the $i$th string from $L(F_1)$ to the $i$th string from $L(F_2)$? in what ordering?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @D.W. thank you for a good remarks. I have made edits.